# Reverse inner and outer margin width in geometry

Tags: margins, geometry, double-sided

In `twoside` mode how to reverse values of inner and outer margin?

By default the outer margin is wider than inner. I search a way to reverse their values and get the inner width in the outer margin, and the outer width in the inner margin.

#### Edit

I mean, the inner and outer parametters are not known by advance because a `\newgeometry` could occur. So, I think, the best way it’s just to catch the value of inner and outer parameters and store them in variable, in order to swap the values.

How to do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand, why don't you just change the values? the `geometry` package has the options `inner` and `outer`.

Comment: Maybe you have an extra page at front of your document? That would cause the pages to flip, so that what you think is outer, is actually inner.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This is a sample document.
\end{document}
```

Try with a long document.

Like this:

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    This is a sample document.
    \lipsum\\
    \lipsum
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’ll modify my question. In the situation you show, the value are well known. But in my question, I want to mean also if the values are not known because a `\newgeometry` command could appear. So I need to store in variable the value off the `inner` parameter to assign it to the outer parameter.

Comment: Sounds like you already know your answer. Just put two new lengths in the preamble: `\newlength\marginone`, `\setlength\marginone{1cm}` and similar for the second margin, and then swap the values after the `\newgeometry`.